# ocmod doesn't overwrite files

Tags: xml, opencart

I have an issue with instalation of the extension on opencart 2 using ocmode. The file does upload and Opencart sais that module is installed. But it doesn't work. The module must show product code in categories. Files aren't overwritten. Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Articles2</name>
    <code>article2</code>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author>Bogdan</author>
    <date>2016.01.31</date>

    <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search>'name'        => $result['name'],</search>
            <add position="before">'model'        => $result['model'],</add>
        </operation>


    </file>
        <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search>&lt;p><?php echo $product['description']; ?>&lt;/p></search>
            <add position="before">&lt;h3>product code:&lt;/h3>    &lt;h4><?php echo $product['model']; ?>&lt;/h4></add>
        </operation>
    </file>




</modification>
```

and the log output

```
2016-01-31 15:48:48 - MOD: Modification Default
FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 39
FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 20
LINE: 59
LINE: 80
LINE: 99
FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 23
FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 25
LINE: 31
----------------------------------------------------------------
MOD: Articles2
FILE: catalog/controller/product/category.php
CODE: 'name'        => $result['name'],
LINE: 216
FILE: catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl
CODE: <p></p>
NOT FOUND!
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

What posibly could go wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Well it sims I found the answer. In search and add tags I had to use [CDATA] Here is an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Articles2</name>
    <code>article2</code>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author>Bogdan</author>
    <date>2016.01.31</date>

    <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA['name'        => $result['name'],]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA['model'        => $result['model'],]]></add>
        </operation>


    </file>
        <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[<h3>product code:</h3>    <h4><?php echo $product['model']; ?></h4>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>




</modification>
```